# the residue at the singular point

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We need to find residue

$\frac{1}{\cos^2z}$

$\cos z=0$

$z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$ - order 2 poles

as the next?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $z_0$ is the pole with order $k$ of $f$ then
Res$(f,z_0)=\frac{1}{k-1!}[(z-z_0)^kf(z)]^{(k-1)}(z_0)$